# Laravel 4.2 - Route keeps failing

Tags: laravel-4, routes

I have an app where,, when my user is logged out or a log-in session expires, for some reason a redirect to a sign in page keeps failing.. I keep searching but I am blind to a solution. Can someone look at this and spot me a problem?

I have a user sign in route:

```
    /*
    | Sign in (GET)
    */
    Route::get('/account/sign-in', array(
        'as' => 'account-sign-in',
        'uses' => 'AccountController@getSignIn'
    ));
```

The getSignIn simply assembles a view:

```
public function getSignIn() {
    return View::make('account.signin');
}
```

I also have the authenticated group routes

```
/*
| Authenticated group
*/
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function() {

    Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin'), function()
    {
        Route::get('/languages', array(
            'as' => 'language-list',
            'uses' => 'LanguageController@getLanguages'
        ));
    });
}
```

And getLanguages is simply like this:

```
public function getLanguages() {

    if( Auth::check()) {

        $languages = Language::all();

        return  View::make('admin.language')->with('languages', $languages);

    } else {

        return Redirect::route('account-sign-in');
    }
}
```

It looks like every time this line gets executed the redirect fails

```
return Redirect::route('account-sign-in');
```

I get this error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException



11. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException
…\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection.php148
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
public function getSignIn() {
    return View::make('account.signin');
}
```

Should be that:

```
public function getSign_in() {
    return View::make('account.signin');
}
```

**Explanation:**

From Illuminate API: `ControllerInspector.php`

```
/**
 * Determine the URI from the given method name.
 *
 * @param  string  $name
 * @param  string  $prefix
 * @return string
 */
public function getPlainUri($name, $prefix)
{
    return $prefix.'/'.implode('-', array_slice(explode('_', snake_case($name)), 1));
}
```

Given that laravel uses `snake_case` to find controller methods, `AccountController@getSignIn` method name in the `Route` `uses` parameter will be converted to *snake case*, which is `getSign_in()`.

Comment: That produces "Method [getSignIn] does not exist." The route works fine when the view is accessed directly. It is not working when I use the "Redirect::route".

Comment: AGHH! I got it..  Languages route was enclosed within auth filtered group "Route::group(array('before' => 'auth')..." my "account-sign-in" is within group with a different filter..